# Recursion error when using the @property and @setter decorators

Tags: python

```
class Phone:
    def __init__(self,brand,model_name,price):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.price = price 
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.price 
    @price.setter
    def price(self,new_value):
        self.price = max(new_value,0)


p1 = Phone('Asus','Asus10',102000)
print(p1.price)
```

Error :

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0):

The property name and the field names are the same. Adding an underscore before the field name can fix it.

```
class Phone:
    def __init__(self,brand,model_name,price):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model_name = model_name
        self._price = price 
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price 
    @price.setter
    def price(self,new_value):
        self._price = max(new_value,0)


p1 = Phone('Asus','Asus10',102000)
print(p1.price)
```